# Alternating between values with rep() in R

Tags: r, apply, rep

I am looking for an elegant way of repeating two values according to a given vector in an alternating fashion. It is better stated by example. Take the following code for instance:

```
vals_to_rep <- c(1, 2)
tms_to_rep <- c(5, 4, 15)
res <- c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 4), rep(1, 15))
res
```

In this example, I wish to repeat the values 1 and 2 according to the vector `tms_to_rep` where I will be starting with 1 (given it is first in the variable) `vals_to_rep`, before alternating to 2, back to 1, ...

I wish to continue this process for the length of `tms_to_rep`-- in this case, three times. The result would look like this:

```
1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

If it helps, you can assume `vals_to_rep` is binary, but no assumptions on length of `tms_to_rep`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expand `vals_to_rep` out to the length of `tms_to_rep`. Then `rep()` works fine:

```
vals_to_rep_expanded = rep(vals_to_rep, length.out = length(tms_to_rep))
rep(vals_to_rep_expanded, times = tms_to_rep)
```

Comment: I didn't even think about that! Thanks friend!